# How to replace all substrings except which are in curly braces using regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all substrings except those which are in curly braces. For example, from such string:

```
let str = 'some text one some text one some text {one} some text';
```

I need to get the following string:

```
str = 'some text two some text two some text {one} some text';
```

I tried this:

```
console.log(str.replace(/one(?!\{one\})/g, 'two'));
```

but got this:

```
some text two some text two some text {two} some text
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capture the character before and after, if they are not `{` and `}`:

```
str.replace(/([^\{])one([^\}])/g, '$1two$2')
```

Comment: you don't need to escape `{}` inside `[]`

Comment: Your answer is simple, intuitive (which really matters) and works perfectly for the case OP has mentioned so this should be the selected answer. Please edit your answer back and remove the edited part.

Answer (score 2):

A basic version of matching would be to use matching whitespace, begin or end. This way it also doesn't capture inside "cones". Which you might or might not want, that's unclear in the question.

`(^|\s)one(\s|$)`

```
let str = 'some text one some text one some text {one} some text';
str.replace(/(^|\s)one(\s|$)/gm, '$1two$2');
console.log(str);
```

In more complex texts, you need to take into account a lot more. E.g. periods and comma's.

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to this,

```
(^|[^{])one(?!\})
```

and replace it with `$1two`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yg7uHH/1)

Here is javascipt sample code,

```js
let str = 'some text one some text one some text {one} some text';
console.log(str.replace(/(^|[^{])one(?!\})/g, '$1two'));
```

This prints following output,

```
some text two some text two some text {one} some text
```

Comment: It is possible to use the first brace? Something like `console.log(str.replace(/(?!\{)one/g, 'two'));` as it is closer to my real problem?

Comment: Javascript doesn't support negative look behind due to which I have used ^|[^{] to ensure, the previous character can be anything but not { or it could be start of string.